# Buying a phone in Europe

Tags: europe, cellphones, luxembourg

I am thinking about buying a locked phone in Luxembourg. The offer looks attractive but I would like to know what happens after the 'subscription' period, for example, if I buy a 24 months plan and throughout this time my phone will be usable only with this specific carrier. Will I be able to use it simply use after the 24 months period or I will have to pay something to the carrier?

I also would be glad to get others' feedback who experience this kind of purchase.

Comment: I am considering Germany, France, Luxembourg, Belgium @Willeke

Comment: @Willeke well but when you are planning to move between all 4 countries it doesn't matter.

Comment: It often does, as buying a phone with a plan often requires an official address in the country you buy it, and with a credit rating in that country. Buying a sim card only (and an unlocked phone in the same or an other shop) can often be done without a proof of address but in some countries you need to register to an official address. Belgium has that rule.

Comment: At least in France, you have the right to unlock your phone six (and even usually three) months after purchase as an operator locked phone. http://www.telecom-infoconso.fr/carte-sim-verrouillage-et-deverrouillage-des-terminaux-mode-demploi/#e

Comment: duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14747/mobile-carrier-and-phones

Comment: It is recommended to look at the cost over the whole period, and in many cases (unless there is a really big promo), you pay less for a phone without SIM card, and a separate price plan.

Comment: It’s a very broad question, it will depend a lot on the actual carrier and plan.

Comment: I thought that nobody sells locked phones nowadays...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about long-term mobile phone contracts, not travel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most useful answer from a comment by @Fattie

In answer to your exact question, generally once you "pay out" the lock period, yes, it's your phone to do what you like with. However there is a HUGE fuss at the end to unlock it. I would truly urge you to simply buy a totally unlocked phone. Buy one now before you leave. Then you can buy any sim you like -- swisscom, Lyca, whatever.